# why .ToList().Distinct() throws error but not the .Distinct().ToList() with linq query

Tags: c#, linq

i'm not able to know the difference between **LinqQuery.ToList().Distinct()** and **LinqQuery.Distinct().ToList();** for me both looks same.

consider this sample code 
:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>();

List<string> str1  = (from item in stringList
                                select item).ToList().Distinct();

List<string> str2 = (from item in stringList
                                 select item).Distinct().ToList();
```

str1 shows an error as : "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

but no error for str2 .

Please help me to understand the diffrence between these two.
Thanks

Comment: "throws" tends to be used to describe an error that occurs at runtime (usually an exception). Whereas this is a compile time error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`.Distinct()` is a method that operates on an `IEnumerable<T>`, and *returns* an `IEnumerable<T>` (lazily evaluated). An `IEnumerable<T>` is a sequence: it is **not** a `List<T>`. Hence, if you want to end up with a list, put the `.ToList()` at the end.

```
// note: this first example does not compile
List<string> str1  = (from item in stringList
                            select item) // result: IEnumerable<string>
                         .ToList() // result: List<string>
                         .Distinct(); // result: IEnumerable<string>

List<string> str2 = (from item in stringList
                             select item) // result: IEnumerable<string>
                         .Distinct() // result: IEnumerable<string>
                         .ToList(); // result: List<string>
```

For illustration of why this is so, consider the following crude implementation of `Distinct()`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
    var seen = new HashSet<T>();
    foreach(var value in source) {
        if(seen.Add(value)) { // true == new value we haven't seen before
            yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In order the str1 to work, add "ToList() at the end. So it would look like tihs : xxx.ToList().Distinct().ToList()

Comment: @Marty that would be undesirable; it creates an unnecessary list in the middle; the existing `str2` code would be preferable.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Just put this in, for better understanding on how to make this work :)

Comment: FYI - If you are dealing with objects rather than strings, Marc's str2 is not equivalent to Marty's comment of ToList().Distinct().ToList().  It depends on what type of object item is.  I have a scenario where Distinct() items are not the same thing as the Distinct() selection.