# C# Linq execute method over results from Distinct() method

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code that will execute Console.WriteLine(x) on every object in what Distinct() will return.

```
objects.Distinct().ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

However, how can I achieve the same thing without using ToList()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using `foreach`:

```
foreach(var x in objects.Distinct())
     Console.WriteLine(x);
```

You don't need the list and you don't need the `List.ForEach` method. Just use a plain loop.

For what it's worth, a [`ForEach` extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/200584/284240) for any kind of sequence.

With this extension method you could use this code:

```
objects.Distinct().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

> .Distinct() is a method that operates on an IEnumerable, and
>   returns an IEnumerable (lazily evaluated). An IEnumerable is a
>   sequence: it is not a List. Hence, if you want to end up with a
>   list, put the .ToList() at the end.

There is a nice explanation for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471937/why-tolist-distinct-throws-error-but-not-the-distinct-tolist-with-linq)

Comment: And why this won't work?

objects.Distinct().Select( x => Console.WriteLine(x))

Comment: @Zwierzak: Two reasons. The first is that you really need something to be returned from your Select. As it is the compiler will complain about that because it can't work out what type your select lambda is returning (because its not). You could fix that with `.Select(x=>{Console.WriteLine(x); return x;})` but then you'd have the problem with lazy evaluation. You wouldn't actually execute the `Console.WriteLine` until you enumerated the `IEnumerable` that you are creating. This would mean either foreaching or using a `ToList()`...

Comment: In other words, trying to make it simple, when you call .Distinc() no action is taken in that moment, it awaits until it's necessary (lazy evaluated), when you call .ToList() the value is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Even being *ugly*, materialization will do (put `.ToList()` at the *end*):

```
objects
  .Distinct()
  .Select(x => {
     Console.WriteLine(x);
     return 1; // <- Select must return something
    })
  .ToList(); // <- this will force Linq to perform Select
```

A much better approach is just *enumerate*:

```
foreach (var x in objects.Distinct())
  Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Comment: Your first code sample gives me an exception, presumably because Console.WriteLine doesn't return anything:  The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway: I see I really have to return something, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by creating your custom `ForEach` extension.

**Test Program**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var objects = new List<DateTime>();

    objects.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
    objects.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
    objects.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
    objects.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
    objects.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(3));
    objects.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(3));
    objects.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(4));
    objects.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(4));
    objects.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(5));
    objects.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(5));

    objects.Distinct().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ToShortDateString()));
}
```

**Extension**

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void ForEach<ST>(this IEnumerable<ST> source, Action<ST> action)
    {
        IEnumerator<ST> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            action(enumerator.Current);
        enumerator.Dispose();
    }

    // OR

    public static void ForEach<ST>(this IEnumerable<ST> source, Action<ST> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
            action(item);
    }
}
```

**PS**

Keep in mind that if you are using LINQ-2-SQL, this won't work since linq2sql queries are only evaluated after some specific actions like `ToList`, `AsEnumerable` or `FirstOrDefault` (and some others).

Comment: Out of interest why are you explicitly enumerating your source rather than just using `foreach`?

Comment: Mostly habits... 2 years ago I've read something about foreach performance and when I've the opportunity I write code with enumerators (When that code won't be seen much).

Comment: But foreach is better since it automatically disposes if the enumerator is disposable.